# Detect the time-elapsed between two WM_LBUTTONUP messages to determine a WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, hook, pinvoke

I'm trying to write an LL-MouseHook that intercepts the clicks out of the application, researching I saw in other sites that seems the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message is unable to be processed as normally and I'm not sure why, but also the MSDN documentation does not list this message as one of the avaliables to process with this kind of hook as you can see in the quote below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Type: WPARAM
>
> The identifier of the mouse message.
>
> This parameter can be one of the following messages:
>
> WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, or WM_RBUTTONUP.

Anyways I'm not sure whether the list is very reliable beacue the middle buttons are not listed there and **CAN** be processed as well.

For that reasons I'm not sure if I'm trying to do this in the better way but I'm trying to follow the instructions given in the solution suggested in this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7149a9a-b366-4983-98ff-5bf8875f67ec/wmlbuttondblclk-capturing-global-doubleclick

> when you intercept a WM_LBUTTONDOWN, save its time by GetMessageTime
>   or GetTickCount function. When you receive the next message, compare
>   the current time with saved one. If the difference is less that the
>   value of GetDoubleClickTime, then this is a double-click.

The problem is that sometimes the double click is not catched, I'm doing the evaluation wrongly in some way.

Someone could help me to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

Here is the relevant code:

```
Private Function LowLevelMouseProc(ByVal nCode As Integer,
                                   ByVal wParam As MouseMessages,
                                   ByRef lParam As NativeMethods.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer

    Static LeftClickTime As Long = 0L

    If nCode = 0I Then

        Select Case wParam

            Case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                RaiseEvent MouseLeftDown(Me, lParam.pt)

            Case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP

                LeftClickTime = GetMessageTime() - LeftClickTime

                If LeftClickTime < GetDoubleClickTime() Then
                    LeftClickTime = 0
                    RaiseEvent MouseLeftDoubleClick(Me, lParam.pt)

                Else
                    RaiseEvent MouseLeftUp(Me, lParam.pt)

                End If

                Debug.WriteLine(LeftClickTime)

            Case Else
                Exit Select ' Do Nothing

        End Select

        Return 0

    ElseIf nCode < 0I Then

        ' Initialize unmanged memory to hold the 'MSLLHOOKSTRUCT' structure.
        Dim pnt As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(lParam))

        Try ' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4ca6d5z7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

            ' Copy the struct to unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(lParam, pnt, False)

            ' Return 
            Return NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, wParam, pnt)

        Finally
            ' Free the unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt)
        End Try

    Else ' nCode > 0

        Return -1I

    End If

End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function GetMessageTime() As Long
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function GetDoubleClickTime() As Long
End Function
```

Then if after running the hook first of all I do a single click (LeftDown + LeftUp) and then a double click (LeftDown + LeftUp + LeftDown + LeftUp), that double click is not interpreted as a double-click and instead of that it fires the `MouseLeftUp` event three times, but in the other hand If after running the Hook first of all I do a single DoubleClick it is detected properly so `MouseLeftDoubleClick` event is fired.

PS: If someone knows a better solution to process the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` out of the application I'm really interested to.

Comment: You dont need all these. You need to process the *lParam* which points to a *MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* struct.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? you mean to read the time value of that struct that contains the timestamp of that message?, maybe thanks to that I could avoid calling the GetMessageTime() function but anyways I imagine that I will fall in the same problem that I exposed (strange wrong time measurement). thanks for your comment

Comment: Not the *time* but the *mouseData*.

Comment: Sorry but I think not, the MSDN documentation says the mousedata is used for the X buttons, otherwise mousedata is not used for anything, and I can confirm that mousedata always is Zero when doing a left click or double click or any other normal mouse event. thanks

Comment: `ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer` for the declaration not as `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to get at the data if you need it.  Windows wont know to do that for you just because you declared it that way.  Cant you just use `Environment.TickCount` to get the relative time?

Comment: You need also a seperate *dll* where your *LowLevelMouseProc* is to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion plutonix but I've tried the `Marshal.PtrToStructure` and I get an unhandled error (in non-english language) it says something like this: `The structure can't be a value Class; Name of parameter: structure`, I'm going step to step and I need to revise your answer in the other question to (try) fix the marshal issue and the declarations. About using `Environment.TickCount` I get the same problem that I described in the question. thanks for your comment

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε its really a need or only a suggestion? due to my ignorance in Hooking I didn't understood the reason of the need of a dll (for this specific case), could you explain it or give some url-refference to learn?. thanks for comment

Comment: examine the MSDN article linked in the other answer; I dont think [`GetMessageTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939(v=vs.85).aspx) will work on its own - it takes no args so how does it know *which* message to get the time for?  It is meant to work with `GetMessage`

Comment: Its ok so one thing improved: I replace with the usage of GetTickCount or Environment.TickCount, but I get the same result (what I said in the end of the question)

Comment: I believe for low level hooks no dll is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the right checks to perform:

```
Case MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP

If LeftClickTime <> 0 Then
    LeftClickTime = (Environment.TickCount() - LeftClickTime)
End If

If (LeftClickTime <> 0) AndAlso (LeftClickTime < GetDoubleClickTime()) Then
    LeftClickTime = 0
    RaiseEvent MouseLeftDoubleClick(Me, lParam.pt)

Else
    LeftClickTime = Environment.TickCount()
    RaiseEvent MouseLeftUp(Me, lParam.pt)

End If
```

This way I have no problems verifying a double-click, at least in the circumstances that I've tested,  and the problem that I described in the end of my question disappeared.